# Getting 2 or more devices to be able to see each other and the internet behind a captive portal

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I'm working from cafes and hotels meaning I have absolutely no access to internet with no captive portal in front of it.

I'm writing mobile app. I need my computer and the phone to be on the same network for debugging and because the computer is serving HTML files for mobile website I'm working on. I also need the computer and the phone to be able to access the internet at the same time. For example chrome has remote debugging but it requires the phone have internet access to download version specific debugging files.

On a typical home network this would be no problem but behind a captive portal I'm not having any luck. The biggest issue is the captive portal presents a web interface that requires login and even if 2 devices log in they can't see each other. I've tried this at 6 cafes and 3 hotels with no luck.

So, solutions?

I have a portable router. I was hoping I could get that to connect to the captive portal and then have my PC and Phone connect to it. Unfortunately as it has no way to respond to the html based login interface I can't seem to do that.

I thought maybe I could use the router as a dumb USB WiFi adaptor. It doesn't seem to have that ability though. In that case I could use the PC to share internet access on one WiFi adaptor out the other. Maybe if I go out and by a real USB WiFi adaptor?

I tried having the PC access the captive portal and then share the internet through the router connected by ethernet cable to the PC. I put the router in router mode (vs ap/bridge/client/repeater/...) I connected the phone wirelessly to the router. That gave both the PC and phone internet but the PC and phone could still not see each other as they were effectively on different networks. Maybe I can setup a route? Not sure how I'd do that on the phone.

Is there another solution?

---

Here's another way to explain this issue. Though I'm not using Phonegap but since it's common, ... Imagine you're making a Phonegap app. The app gets data from a server. You're testing/debugging so you're running that server locally on your PC. You launch the your debug build of your phone gap app. It makes `GET` requests to `http://<ipaddresofpc>/endpoint`

On a normal home router your phone and your PC can ping either other. On 99% of all captive portal managed networks (think Hotels, Starbucks, Cafes, Airports) your phone and PC *cannot* ping each other. Communication between devices over WiFi is blocked for some reason.

The question is how to work around that given you only have access to a captive portal (ie, you're at starbucks connected to their WiFi). You need both your phone and your PC to have internet access and you need them to be able to ping either other as well.

---

Update: Actually I was wrong. The phone and the PC can see each other with the last setup. The Phone see's the PC has its gateway and is able to see the web server running on the PC.

Comment: Hmm. Is your issue resolved after your last update? If yes, please close the question. If no, please simplify your question. It is not very clear exactly what you are asking (especially after your last update)

Comment: What's not clear? The question is "how to get 2 devices to see each other behind a captive portal". Seems pretty straight forward question. I found a solution. I can post that solution as an answer. I can make the question a wiki entry. But the point of stackexchange sites is to post questions and answers. I asked a question, I provided an answer. That could clearly be useful others. That's 1000% inline with what this site is about. Maybe there are other answers others could suggest as well. I'm not seeing how by any guideline on this site this question should be closed.

Comment: A better solution would be to just connect your phone directly to your PC.

Comment: And how does that help? There is no networking cable to connect my PC to my Phone and as stipulated above my Phone needs to be getting files served as web pages from my PC. In other words the phone needs to see the PC on the network. All USB gives me is debugging. It doesn't let the phone browser webpages from my phone.